# How to display date of a current month with the month and year in Java?

Tags: java, date

How to display the date, month, and year of a particular month in for loop dynamically in Java?

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please tag it as such.

Comment: Also, you're better served showing what you've tried so far and describing a specific problem you've encountered rather than simply trying to get people to hand out free code that solves your problem.

Comment: what have you tried? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: No. Am trying in a different manner.Please give me suggestions.

Comment: what i tried is divided the sundays and saturdays of a month seperately.And iam trying a simple program.

Comment: In my application,am entering the employee details.And i created a table named as empdet.And also am updating the values to database.One of those fields,one field is date.

Comment: i'm sorry but in order to get an answer you should make the question in [SO] format.

Comment: Date is storing in dd-mm-yyyy, format.With that reference to date,i want to display the emp details.

Comment: Check out the java.util.Calendar class:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: *"what i tried is.."* For better help sooner, post an ***[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)*** of your best effort, and add a specific question as to how to implement an aspect of the next stage.

Comment: How Can i show only dates of a particular month in dd-mm-yyyy format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This demonstrates briefly some of the basics of the `SimpleDateFormat` and `GregorianCalendar` classes in Java.  It was the best I could do based on your question.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int year = 2012;
        int month = 4;

        /* The format string for how the dates will be printed. */
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

        /* Create a calendar for the first of the month. */
        GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, 1);

        /* Loop through the entire month, day by day. */
        while (calendar.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) == month) {
            String dateString = format.format(calendar.getTime());
            System.out.println(dateString);

            calendar.add(GregorianCalendar.DATE, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0):

## Using java.time

The other Answer uses the troublesome old date-time classes, now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

### Time zone

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

### `YearMonth`

We care about the whole month. So use a [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) object to represent that.

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.from( today );
```

Get the first of the month.

```
LocalDate localDate = ym.atDay( 1 );
```

Loop, incrementing the date by one day at a time, until past the end of month. We can test that fact by seeing if each incremented date has the same `YearMonth` as today. Collect each date in a `List`.

```
List<LocalDate> dates = new ArrayList<>( 31 );  // Collect each date. We know 31 is maximum number of days in any month, so set initial capacity.
while( YearMonth.of( localDate).equals( ym ) ) {  // While in the same year-month.
    dates.add( localDate ); // Collect each incremented `LocalDate`.
    System.out.println( localDate );
    // Set up next loop.
    localDate = localDate.plusDays( 1 );
}
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).